# Call to Amazon Web Service not styled by attached XSLT stylesheet

Tags: xml, xslt, amazon-web-services

To those who have already helped me thanks.  I am rephrasing my question to perhaps get a different angle on the problem I have.

Can anyone see why this call to Amazon Web Services (AWS) would not get styled by the stylesheet which is applied in the call?  The call is:

```
    Dim REST = "http://ecs.amazonaws.co.uk/onca/xml?Service=AWSECommerceService&AssociateTag=xxxx&SubscriptionId=zzzz&Operation=BrowseNodeLookup&BrowseNodeLookup.1.BrowseNodeId=676410011&BrowseNodeLookup.2.BrowseNodeId=676398011&BrowseNodeLookup.1.ResponseGroup=TopSellers,NewReleases&BrowseNodeLookup.2.ResponseGroup=TopSellers,NewReleases&Style=http://www.wiiuser.co.uk/topsellersnewrel.xslt"
```

This call is then passed through a signature routine and the file loaded to be processed.

The stylesheet is found here:

http://www.wiiuser.co.uk/topsellersnewrel.xslt

The call to AWS returns the correct data in an xml file.

When the stylesheet is tested seperately by embedding the stylesheet in the xml file directly it doesn't work either, even though for a couple of years it worked perfectly.

The only thing that AWS have changed is the to update the API version 
from
http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2005-10-05
to
http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01

The call, without a '&style=...' applied, returns results with the 2005 date. All other calls on my sites now return xml dated 2011.  I've noticed that the date issue only seems to be for BrowseNodeLookups.

If anyone can see a problem with the xslt file or tell me if there is a change in the way BrowseNodeLookupsare handled please tell me.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Could you post the XML returned by the call without the `&style=` part?